# Find deprecated API in Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api

I have a message stating our Google Apps domain is using an API that will be deprecated soon.  When I look at the list of upcoming APIs I don't see any I believe we are using, but I have copied some code from various example sources and may be missing something.  Outside looking at every line of code in the various spreadsheets, forms, etc, is there a way to determine what code in what files might be using an API which is about to go away?  If I have o manually look at them all I am sure to miss something.  And if it i in an old test script I can gladly throw them away.  Just trying to most efficiently find any problems as we area  non-profit and all my time has been volunteer time that is better spent on new directions.

Regards,
Karl S

Comment: The "Execution Hints" lightbulb is helpful, but only if you actually RUN the offending code in the editor. And its almost no help if the problematic code is in a library.

Comment: @Mogsdad I have been doing that through some of the code but other is more difficult to hit via the editor. Plus, I do have a couple libraries.  Hopefully it is just something from an old test item or was from an add-on we are not using and I removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a report from your admin console to see where in your domain scopes have been authorized.

https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?#Reports:subtab=token-audit

Here you can search for the scopes of the depreciating apis.  If found it will return the app associated with them

Here are the scopes that are depreciating.

```
https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/.*?/(user|nickname|emailList)/
```

And

```
https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/(group|user|alias|customer|orgunit|orguser)/
```

Comment: so if I find no instance of `https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/` or even `/a/feeds/` then I should be good?  I did find that an add-on we do not use reported issues under Admin panel, Security->More->Advanced Settings->Manage API client access. Since this is not used I removed it from use.

Comment: I used the advice from @Spencer above, but changed my look for requests to 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/' and 'https://docs.googleusercontent.com/' and 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/' which got me to 1 file that used 'DocList.' which I upgraded to 'DriveApp'.  I found these using the same information provided by Mogsdad above regarding the lightbulb icon.